# Detecting tabbars selected view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

I created a project using tabbar apllication and storyboard.

Now i have FirstViewController (which is selected by default) and SecondViewController.

How do i catch the moment when the selected view controller changes? (the user selects second view controller on tabbar).

The only way i thought of is:
1. Make a property for UITabBarController in appDelegate.

1. Set it using 
       `self.tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController`
2. Make the first view controller conform to UITabBarControllerDelegate.
3. Set the tabbar's delegate to FirstViewController using 
       `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`

Is there a simpler and cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't follow the third step, but here's what I think you want to do:

Subclass tab bar controller and implement the delegate protocol:

`@interface RootTabBarController : UITabBarController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>`

and set its delegate = self in its own viewDidLoad. Implement:

`- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController`